# Azure ARM templates in Github Actions Keyvault Policies

Tags: azure, github-actions, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, azure-bicep

I have a .bicep file which creates my cloud resources one of which is a new keyvault into which I am able to store connection strings from the different resources e.g ACR username/password, redis connection string, etc.
The .bicep file is referenced in a github actions workflow with the action azure/arm-deploy@v1
I need to be able to access the secrets downstream but for that I would need to run something  that updates the keyvault policy to allow the service principal I am using to call the github action workflow get/list permissions. I tried using this:

```
      - name: set policies
    continue-on-error: true
    env:
      clientId: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
    run: |
      az keyvault set-policy -n kv-dev-lightningocr --secret-permissions get list set --spn $clientId
```

but the $clientId is not inserted as expected as shown in the snapshot below:
[image]

It is possible to set policies directly in the .bicep template but I am having issues with that because I'm not sure how I can substitute the value for the objectId in the template.

```
    resource keyVaultPolicies 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies@2021-06-01-preview' = {
  name: '${keyVault.name}/add'
  properties: {
    accessPolicies: [
      {
        tenantId: subscription().tenantId
        objectId: // how to get the objectId of the service principal that calls the azure deploy action? 
        permissions: {
          keys: []
          secrets: [
            'get'
            'list'
          ]
          certificates: []
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have crawled through the microsoft documentation but it feels like looking for a needle in a haystack, so any specific answers to this very specific question are much aprpeciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is ***not possible to reference the Azure AD objects from a ARM template*** ***except for the ones which are associated to the Azure resources*** as a `System-Assigned Identity` or `User-Assigned Identity`.

***Example to reference `System-Assigned Identity` or `User-Assigned Identity` of a virtual machine :***

```
"[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', variables('vmName')),'2019-12-01', 'Full').identity.principalId]",
```

The only way for now is to ***get the Service principal object id*** from ***`Portal`*** or using ***`Azure AD Powershell module`*** or ***`az CLI`*** or ***`copy the clientID from the environment variable`*** that you have stored for the ***`Github Actions`***.

**Then you can directly paste it in the below bicep template:**

```
  resource keyVaultPolicies 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies@2021-06-01-preview' = {
  name: '${keyVault.name}/add'
  properties: {
    accessPolicies: [
      {
        tenantId: subscription().tenantId
        objectId:// copied from portal, az cli,powershell or environment variable
        permissions: {
          keys: []
          secrets: [
            'get'
            'list'
          ]
          certificates: []
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

---

***The below way you are using the environment variable is also wrong.***

```
name: set policies
    continue-on-error: true
    env:
      clientId: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
    run: |
      az keyvault set-policy -n kv-dev-lightningocr --secret-permissions get list set --spn $clientId
```

`${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}` will contain something like below and you are referencing the `clientid` using the whole `Azure_credential` Environment Variable which is not possible.

```
  {
    "clientId": "<GUID>",
    "clientSecret": "<GUID>",
    "subscriptionId": "<GUID>",
    "tenantId": "<GUID>",
    (...)
  }
```

***`AZURE_CREDENTIALS` is used as a credential variable for logging into the Azure like below :***

```
steps:
    # checkout the repo
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: Azure/login@v1
      with:
        creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
```

***So, in the Github actions also you will have to hard code it like below :***

```
name: set policies
    continue-on-error: true
    run: |
      az keyvault set-policy -n kv-dev-lightningocr --secret-permissions get list set --spn <ClientID>
```

**Reference:**

[Quickstart - Use Azure Key Vault secrets in GitHub Actions workflows | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/github/github-key-vault)

[Setting Key Vault Access Policy from Azure Pipelines](https://salmanalibanani.com/2020/11/20/setting-key-vault-access-policy-from-azure-pipelines/)

Comment: Thank you. This is a let down. I am against hard coding anything. I want all of my code to be driven by configuration. But from your answer it sounds like it is impossible. I will leave this question open for now and if no one else adds a solution I will mark yours as accepted.

Comment: Your answer was correct and it pointed me in the right direction. I added processes that involve more manual steps one of which is to create a SP and put the credentials in a persistent key vault from which the ARM template is able to pull credentials as needed.